# In "Sicario" who did the "knife-kills" in the first part of the tunnel scene?

Tags: sicario

Who was the team leader that did the 2 "knife kills" in the begining of the tunnel scene in *Sicario*?

Answer (score 1):

It was a member of Delta leading the pack, using his knife to try and maintain an optimum level of stealth until the other members can reach the complexes centre and launch their '4th of July on steroids' action and Alejandro can divert down the side tunnel.

Everyone except Alejandro has night vision, so whenever we see Deakins use images from the thermal goggles, we know it is Alejandro's POV, as he is the only member of the team to have this piece of equipment.

The positions of the squads leaders are supported by the script which goes as follows...

> We drop into a ravine and follow it. Up ahead we see the brush and the
> old car that is hood first in the ground, like it was dropped from the
> sky. The team lines up across from it.
>
> MATT (CONT’D) (Into mouthpiece) Where is the  target?
>
> VOICE Bout twenty minutes to the border.
>
> MATT (To Delta)We need to boogie. And we  need to do it quiet till we
> find the center.
>
> Delta pulls his knife. Alejandro comes up to the front.

[SICARIO SCRIPT INDIEGROUND FILMS](https://indiegroundfilms.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/sicario-by-taylor-sheridan.pdf)